# Web service - exclude authentication - IIS 7.0 Web Config

Tags: windows

We are using IIS 7.0 as the web servers - It's configured to access IBM WAS6 application server on a different server.
We recently implemented Single Sign on with Ping Identity Management Solution. The identity management solution implemented is being invoked for the application correctly - We need to exclude this for the web services, which are part of our application running on WAS
The application URL has the following URL structure  http://test.com/appname/services/Service

We have tried including location path section in IIS web.config but it does not seem to take effect.
How do we include config changes in web.config to include exclusion logic to avoid authentication when this web service is invoked on the application server

Any help is greatly appreciated..